# How to implement a concurrency control in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, concurrency

I want to learn about concurrency in .NET. I created an ASP.NET MVC project with a `[timestamp]` annotation to learn about but I can't edit any objects, they never return anything. What should I change in my method?

My class:

```
public class Employee
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

My edit method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,RowVersion")] Employee employee)
{
    if (id != employee.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            if (!EmployeeExists(employee.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

Comment: show the view/code that is posting the data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps only to change signature of `Edit` method?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromBody] Employee employee)
{
        //...
}
```

Comment: no, unfortunately it didn't work.